# Why can I not add config location to Spring exectuable jar on windows using "-Dspring.config.location"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

I have a simple CMD line app that uses an executable jar. I want to externalize the properties files. Per the docs I see this should be possible but it isn't working for me. I have the following...

```
- root
  - target
    lib.jar
  - src
    -test
      -resources
       *.properties
```

I try running from the target directory like...

```
java -Dspring.config.location=file:///i:/...../src/test/resources -jar lib.jar PARAM
```

I also tried..

```
java -Dspring.config.location=file:///i:/...../src/test/resources/ -jar lib.jar PARAM
```

The application is pretty straight forward...

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"my.pkg.*"})
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        service.doSomething();
    }
}
```

But when I run it cannot find the files...

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [*.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

What am I missing I tried other combos for the file path like

```
file:i:\.....\src\test\resources -jar lib.jar
```

But still no luck. This is because even though I know the path is correct I am not sure how Java is expecting it when coming from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

From the doc :

```
If spring.config.location contains directories (as opposed to files) they should end in / (and will be appended with the names generated from spring.config.name before being loaded).
```

Comment: Adding the slash did not help